# What is the meaning of "sga_max_size= # internally adjusted"

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I used following command to get backup of my spfile.

```
CREATE PFILE='c:/test_init.ora' FROM MEMORY;
```

it has following lines related to memory.

```
memory_max_target=12G
memory_target=8G
__java_pool_size=16M
log_buffer=4743168 # log buffer update
__pga_aggregate_target=6G
_pga_max_size=1258280K
processes=400
sga_max_size=2G # internally adjusted
__sga_target=2G
__shared_io_pool_size=0
__shared_pool_size=704M
_smm_max_size=629140
_smm_min_size=1024
_smm_px_max_size=3145728
```

I wonder about "# internally adjusted" comment. What does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

It means it was adjusted by Oracle, because it was not specified explicitly.
When using Automatic Memory Management, you need to set only the memory_target parameter, the sga/pga parameters are handled internally by the database automatically.

Answer (score 2):

It means that possibly some other DBA issued the command below (alter system with optional comment clause). Then the comment is put into spfile this way. But as I read metalink note: 257643.1 it might some outcome of some changes in automatic memory management.

See alter system command:

`alter system set sga_max_size=2G scope=spfile sid=* comment='internally adjusted';`